# SQL Server 2016 Maintenance Plan Editor - Add Annotation Not Working

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016, maintenance-plan

I'm using: -

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU15-GDR) (KB4583461) - 13.0.5865.1 (X64)

SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18384.0

I have created a brand new Maintenance Plan for a Daily Backup.
The Maintenance Plan works fine and does the backup.
However, I would like to add an Annotation, but each time I click "Add Annotation" nothing happens. I have used it before on many other projects, so I know how it should work.

[image: Add Annotation Fails]

I've also tried cut-n-pasting an Annotation from a Maintenance Plan on another server running SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR), and just get an error. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

[image: Paste Annotation Fails]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with that particular version of SSMS. Upgrading to SSMS 18.9.2 fixed it.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/483074/sql-server-2016-maintenance-plan-editor-add-annota.html